# Script that increases a page-view counter

Tags: python

Someone I know has a website which uses statcounter.com. I'm trying to write a python script which simply accesses the page in order to increase this number. I don't know much about web programming in general, or if the statcounter service would be able to prevent against such a thing.

I have tried the naive approach:

```
import urllib.request

for i in range(100):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen('WEBSITE-URL-HERE')
```

However, this does not impact the statcounter. It is also notably very slow. Any advice on how to proceed is thanked in advance.

Comment: I don't know about statcounter specifically, but services like these typically get the site designer to include a bit of script or some other resource in their page that causes a page load to hit the server. The server may simply recognise that the requests are all coming from the same address and not count them under certain conditions. You can try stuff like spoofing the user agent type or varying your request to make it look like a different one, but you're basically trying to do what statcounter is supposed to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by single request.

"The great advantage of web trackers are that they are better at tracking 'real people' as they track browsers NOT server requests. This often means a web tracker will have a significantly lower count than standard log file analysis. But it offers a more realistic figure of the visitors to your website and far more detail. At StatCounter our web tracker is provided in real-time so it's even better still."

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests

# Set up the URL you want to view
url = "https://www.example.com"

# Set up a loop to view the URL 500 times
for i in range(500):
  # Send a GET request to the URL
  response = requests.get(url)

  # Print the response status code
  print(f"Request {i+1}: {response.status_code}")
```